# Windows 10 Cannot change This PC -> Documents location to default

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

So I was messing around with OneDrive and decided to go back to Google Drive after seeing the change from 15GB storage to 5. My Documents folder under This PC was set to my OneDrive folder, and after copying everything under the OneDrive folder back to `C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Documents`, I disabled OneDrive.

Now This PC -> Documents links to the old OneDrive folder which is no longer in use, and I cannot change the directory when right clicking Documents -> Properties -> Location -> Restore Default.

I have admin rights on the machine under this account. I have full admin rights for the Documents folder which is currently linked to `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\OneDrive\Documents`. I have full admin rights to the folder that I want to move it to `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents`. However, when clicking Restore Default under locations I receive the error:

> The folder can't be moved here. Access is denied.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  Had to run a batch file that closes explorer.exe first.  Found at [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1069344/windows-10-cannot-change-this-pc-documents-location-to-default)